# growth of the permanent of some band matrix

Tags: co.combinatorics, matrices, permanent

Consider such special band matrix of dimension $n$. It is a $0-1$ matrix, and only the first few diagonals are nonzero. Specifically,

$$ H_{ij} = 1 $$

if and only if $|i-j| \leq 2$.

How does the permanent grow with $n$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The permanent of this matrix [is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permanent_(mathematics)#Perfect_matchings) the number of perfect matchings of the graph $G_n$ that consists of vertices $\{(a,b):a\in\{ 1,...,n\},b\in\{0,1\}\}$ and the only edges are between $(i,0)$ and $(j,1)$ where $|i-j|\leq 2$.

Given a matching on the graph $G_n$, we define a sequence of graphs $G_{n-1},...,G_1$: $G_{k-1}$ is formed by removing from $G_k$ the vertex with the lexicographically smallest label and its neighbour in the matching.

The map from a matching to the sequence is injective, so the number of such sequences is the number of matchings in $G_n$.

If we start from $G_n$, then there are only five types of graphs in the sequence ${G_{n-1},...,G_1}$. They are shown in the figure as vertex sets (as all these graphs are induced subgraphs of $G_n$), above the long line. Call them $A_k$, $B_k$, $C_k$, $D_k$ and $E_k$, respectively, where the $k$s are the length of the lines above the patterns.

[image: transfer matrix]

The graphs below the long line shows the possibilities of $G_{k-1}$ if $G_k$ is isomorphic to one of the graphs shown above.

Take the first column as an example. The graph above the long line is $A_k$, and the graphs below are $A_{n-1}$, $B_{k-2}$ and $C_{k-3}$. It means if $G_k$ is an $A_k$, then $G_{k-1}$ is an $A_{k-1}$, a $B_{k-2}$ or a $C_{k-3}$.

By doing substitutions, or in terms of the graph sequence, compressing consecutive $G_k$s into a single step, we obtain the following substitutions.

[image]

The equations are

$$A_k=A_{k-1}+B_{k-2}+B_{k-3}+A_{k-3}+A_{k-4}$$

$$B_k=A_k+B_{k-1}$$

or $$\left[\begin{matrix}A_k \\ A_{k-1} \\ B_{k-1} \\ A_{k-2} \\ B_{k-2} \\ A_{k-3}\end{matrix}\right]=\left[ \begin{matrix} 1 && 0 && 1 && 1 && 1 && 1 \\ 1 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 \\ 1 && 0 && 1 && 0 && 0 && 0 \\ 0 && 1 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 \\ 0 && 0 && 1 && 0 && 0 && 0 \\ 0 && 0 && 0 && 1 && 0 && 0 \end{matrix}    \right] \left[\begin{matrix}A_{k-1} \\ A_{k-2} \\ B_{k-2} \\ A_{k-3} \\ B_{k-3} \\ A_{k-4}\end{matrix}\right]$$

where $A_k$ and $B_k$ both denote the graphs and the number of perfect matchings in them.

The characteristic polynomial of the matrix is $x^6 - 2x^5 - 2x^3 + x$, with largest root approximately $2.333554225170094$, so the permanent grows like $c*2.333554225170094^n$ for some constant $c$.

Comment: It seems that this is a well studied problem in graph theory. Actually the matrix I am interested in is not a 0-1 matrix. I put all the nonzero elements to 1 just for simplicity, hoping that the scaling behavior is captured by the 0-1 matrix.

Comment: It is really a smart solution!

Answer (score 7):

Another way of looking at this permanent is that it is the number of permutations $\pi$ of $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ satisfying $|\pi(i)-i|\le 2$ for all $i$. The generating function for these permutations is $$\frac{1-x}{1-2x-2x^3+x^5},$$ which is consistent with LeechLattice's answer. The sequence of coefficients is [A002524](https://oeis.org/A002524) in the OEIS.

A nice combinatorial derivation of this generating function can be found in Example 4.7.18 (pages 514–515) in Richard Stanley's *Enumerative Combinatorics, Volume I*, second edition. (It's Example 4.7.16, pages 252–253, in the first edition.)

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is also very impressive.

Comment: You mean Example 4.7.7?

Comment: No, it's not Example 4.7.7. I have added some clarification to my answer.