# Acyclic matching property in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: co.combinatorics, additive-combinatorics, cyclic-groups

Let $B$ be a finite subset of the group $G$ which does not contain the neutral element. For any subset $A$ in $G$ with the same cardinality as $B$, a matching from $A$ to $B$ is defined to be a bijection $f : A \rightarrow B$ such that for any $a \in A$ we have $a + f(a) \notin A$. For any matching $f$ as above, the associated multiplicity function $m_f : G \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$ is defined via the rule: $\forall x \in G$, $m_f(x) = |\{a \in A : a + f(a) = x\}|$. A matching $f : A \rightarrow B$ is called acyclic if for any matching $g: A \rightarrow B$, $m_f = m_g$ implies $f = g$. A group $G$ has the acyclic matching property if for any pair of subsets $A$ and $B$ in $G$ with $|A| = |B|$ and $e \notin B$, there is at least one acyclic matching from $A$ to $B$. It is proved [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1508.03934.pdf) (Propositions 2.2 and 2.3) that there are infinitely many prime $p$ for which $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ does not have the acyclic matching property.

Question: Classify all primes with respect to the acyclic matching property. In particular, can we show that for $p > 5$, $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ does not have the acyclic matching property?

Update 1: Some useful numerical experiments are found in this [paper](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/271586/1-s2.0-S0024379519X00178/1-s2.0-S0024379519303416/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEPP%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJIMEYCIQDiUSeAzLcOHodmrp%2BsSYPVCa%2FmxTygCF411d7eneY1LQIhAK1uFZaS1tPhqFVA8lc4xR9NZpLt8rQcrVTrB98NRjXNKrwFCKz%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEQBRoMMDU5MDAzNTQ2ODY1IgwqlmYdMhMewOuxd4UqkAXvHq7HwAxK0iGiwOJrIH5GnvshA5fi%2BMZCX3bu0fThhPBwE4uFJXMY6fWOXdyDPoNt2OKrKXkHtKLUIwdAto%2F9OB956IdCPkeIHBEd7c095HT%2B%2BEgwZcv0E1piOn2PhM2Q8cfsNIONAH3e5uZrt0Htbtxre%2FJHHIZcRBa18l1oLO5SH9uGvPRHK2tD582UpbrGToTI6TBVntPFwlO9dKrquBjT%2FJaNF76qz0weT8oOYIlnoVuFNJpaJp3aYCNYLdyGtvNpvetrgQ757dsAFJNDXvvVGJUspcwFGRhKhJIPh73CsAHk%2FsFs3Rgj1nBciW41S9nl4NC8U1nmYXH8FS1A4vVJJkPebzqtYyL9MbA1UChSaDUGHFu1AbL7nbntKS0XWBGuSpkqox7445IvcTE%2Fm0FKBUB6gtcDJRqC9vd2AWkfENkyyzOYaccy1LtXYr4aEkKHChiXD8LDHyyt0X8Xj%2FSjb4PiAKxlW%2FFEF2JGtdGf8M2xTIgdH3POGZD3RRSVo226YrDfBLwP2HlGi5AvHdvKC4JzicMfh11CIp0V7D5dt6j7ectwGAdoQIdS0wjwV5Pkbxn6YVuyrvSZP%2BPWYV%2BBgfAut2F9nKA22A4sUGk%2BEusP9QMa1a1ER%2Bm0W%2Bp%2F2pCVkCPaHfgPa%2BXBURmFWUI5FR9NRTvECQdQgMPbNZZWiQ9n%2BfXYtu7AIqWF1wnV1x7TGr%2FyAfWO7N0e%2FhNpeuJc0h77aOzA726WvdWknk18zeFVaqcyHNz%2FZIcaUOXiM025rJ1NiVNWqLJkCAqIbGtuXiTm8rMp0o9UlMLCz4HhIihK8yI8Po4qd5ehTmXTX0wZWwc6yl9mOxOWdYUkX9ARhOMPfTFZiwdKQKfetjDH%2B8%2BtBjqwAYorBfZm%2BFlw7LuJrz86jdVb4E5XRUk2xG48MBU02oGMB723OAGkWv0DqN23zPyZQeJSBXqamM6UsKYlUf3tlrEn9PbCmb8RSxzW7iMne0KxMjN2jGu8PFQjPDexHq6MRFUDhkxBVh2g9tzJ4UkvUmbkIyZ7iWkeYbbD%2B5a%2FccAOVSyoZLYVw0%2BQ87xOvEzAkldmsbHDSfxrBMRJXt3rrEnz8xQLtFvEXfRg1A5Vwz51&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20240126T202106Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTY6UAAD6WG%2F20240126%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=72d601cddb34951b59c83b117d354194ee97b5cfa89ad04b77860aeba8817c0c&hash=448d5fd146fb9cd3df57d144267a307c285d8c59d6f1ca7ea8e68a6e47430121&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=S0024379519303416&tid=spdf-403b5d28-18cc-486d-98ad-81682cc3931a&sid=566514e34b22a24dda19d449f008bdb49cbbgxrqa&type=client&tsoh=d3d3LnNjaWVuY2VkaXJlY3QuY29t&ua=0f135a56040553540400&rr=84bb75da6dcf2f4b&cc=us), page 17, for $p\leq 19$.

Update 2: In this [paper](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/272585/1-s2.0-S0001870800X00898/1-s2.0-S0001870896900602/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEPf%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJIMEYCIQDLUNhBBSlbd0RurDJTdZDvRWregFV%2BIn9nLW%2B1E8U4tQIhAKMFxIQh06ME3YS2A5DDQTzXrBPhq8zv6vzdapV%2BZRNVKrwFCLD%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEQBRoMMDU5MDAzNTQ2ODY1IgxRNcgBUgRveOU5SgoqkAUEuV0IMWHUXMNPkEt3fxQAGJ4OjHxSZCsouuKc%2FZC7uSAvGna3iJn5dgh6HaXnP60Vw%2FAnRORwd%2BXEGrMy%2FoK8swhWT79mswJj8U%2BFyKmOS0exNXi87wZADIADRKrhqEVFPZVOqCKBCtXAelPZog68DIh9uUGoS%2B6ItzkUs9sUZS%2FQ4LIbynYAKaoEzyvb3Kn%2FO0R4i8jcVcTxvv%2B7yN8H6ICsO%2F%2F8702XvnSQBWwRmSRDPJWlEljqf%2FM1JN6dB%2FptWlZvXZcOSKAp%2F3tSIuEyt46oJJtBYz6o0vcbVoSCMRXD6oKpJFY1YNcJx6fFzkvKdohgMmuPKKnHuOpMPNzHLUVHrVpbzjvblQG7eCCXDs64jGyZT5d58%2FyQBdWgi3xCLnujqJJw3rEaAfMxTe%2By0LF%2FgQ7mln8I0jvzlVycHGCCeckNnOjStYuJqPEvr70fNiJA0VzKQCqpLiSavo0jP2orlLdr1%2FXjquhByg6Lxa8qU%2Fq8DALjs0GEljng6Zr75k4Uw6wmmHD6Ua6TN9evNLrJ%2FBF9zqvnXvMWgHsEDD6F79UwTnnb3MXqkLXm%2FwLuN0UJSGqPPVp1Cb%2BUt2SZqJdR0trCWV3uiwMupZBihnhrtKgxcH33wibuqV7WY310o9mkRqI%2B7zu3LpjVEfuLUcqgqDLMrH7UlPl1aZO9fCz2aeqv1pz3QtISVmtm4UY3Lb3vxhvvIP6K%2Fc4nX2BH62ENhVKqSGxEGJ%2FhfEvLtQOKr5zlZsGKC%2BWAJBrAgT9npxUNAIA3Rm3H0GB4rjLC7l%2FgHHbU0b4iMVto7vYaWNGgoBBRIoeR8vBx8scy70WeSF8wDjr2VZpM29RzOoYFyN%2FgseWjy%2BRe4Gqthw8VFDDn6dCtBjqwAWSsCz1pKRW2y%2F6pPCZnwa4t994hpgWaokLYjmwEv0RP90qTKAKCmayRGRBMGAHdmg5HFYnzTQYRB4Mf8DHFUccQJHXDd%2FYdjhW0mfUsZQ9Lfec%2Brm3u3yWoqPa1kSfSShHv96%2BWrTLTjavbyr5mhFaOdD%2F5jbVfaB5%2Bde8Fk01TCio54dQKtZkcyeLNIulGAA5yNg%2Fu8rpSlfUemgTfGXsIzgAAWAo7LKKpSIsSH6%2Fn&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20240126T232656Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTYZIOBKEXC%2F20240126%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=e2c1a8b3ce5821c7df3b23ff6a5159a5c43a42734cd38d3c5c58fc374b7dab9e&hash=3f489d2cadf7b2d2d671dcf5b764ce971d3a4ec9cca4bf2f54426dabc7077330&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=S0001870896900602&tid=spdf-1bec6d83-3695-4be7-bf53-d04d84e2d3a8&sid=566514e34b22a24dda19d449f008bdb49cbbgxrqa&type=client&tsoh=d3d3LnNjaWVuY2VkaXJlY3QuY29t&ua=0f135a5604045c575007&rr=84bc860f7bc408d3&cc=us), Alon et al. prove that the additive group $\mathbb{Z}^n$ (and in general, any abelian torsion-free group) possesses the acyclic matching property.

Update 3: Counterexamples usually occurs when $|A|=|B|=\frac{p-1}{2}$ or $\frac{p+1}{2}$.

Update 4: It is proved in this [paper](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/272528/1-s2.0-S0196885800X00267/1-s2.0-S0196885898905875/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEDwaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJGMEQCIHU7lAI2fLUstQjvzNnO2KQEiFWlbhOz%2B2wH%2FVOV6YUUAiB92sYIYV9d%2FMcaZayJEfIfOKWc%2BEHJy5t2uHYjhd6U0yq7BQj0%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F8BEAUaDDA1OTAwMzU0Njg2NSIMXlRJnNDao1ErG0a9Ko8FUh3UkSkYHvWpEJrVMkGNL0yss1sczTqUmLnGRkoOskBaJmxqmD9tf7kul4%2FosGomBfI%2B3Vv5vXDwh%2BQtlDFdMR2mH2GPSoMKmpCVNcY3g7tyQtgmt%2FRpStreYPBddsj3tlcwNVbNZc%2Bwnp1XWoGvd%2FDQYeog1JgNkXlREPK3GARIhB2W7i9c8rA0kSbE3PQzBd4O%2Ba1r354OkffaM8fHELR3g7dfYfTcGBuf2I7cc%2BEU4vcxuf3sOmiseFvkUKAAxdBLgWYLTpuYLp332oy0j5aemEvJQpjpGPZuz4YqyplSXXWBFmSRLWy92YAD9r8eE4cHnzXjteZV%2FubDfJWkZhesdnR6a5QjTAfm6euP1yq%2FHgh9uMM9Wux2A1Up80bSstJPip8bvY%2B0Z9MaIbmnaruKmOG8M84zRRhFSNn8nd9Y5b1JRsSfoRj%2BljYlOX0dPNiDp5yE%2F98t89zv4EloL1WafYSQ3ReoyeXhQLqo%2FQohnHeNpeFhsBi0I7O8RF98ea3%2BG%2Br0xo6xOm2fmhsonTM%2FU1VWEGbNmATt3IYu7B23St4LkyKORUnFdnzp3ViY%2FIrib8vLJYTJqAv0u927WIYIkI%2Bx2nyOd%2FLtIeDr8gbxIpmK7at7x77BheTfgAHgh7cSFx4laNLTOs0%2Fr39QqGaqtXSWRnbO0Nb6HVXG6ttWAOJKMj5zE29M2HhOUFYkeMEC8wG8JTa00lHBpyFfoOfrXhmkmZ2hgCHweHGRuoMOB7%2FBEBiRYz%2BdkPC9RfoWt%2BZSG1Groh00ZHGbtS08KKO4U5h7kTddNaFKfACgmVWxJ0NVspaxuq%2B847gDODFAOp1Pq4Px3inn7x1DtGdeLu6S92dI7A4InqhRTWwc8DDs89%2BtBjqyAV%2B3p8aUPlXvOQ13Z%2BnQ4VkiQs4UOgGEtBdlRkDoazWMAYXrG5yHnWVKQY1diuNtle9S%2BydvzMnI5izdBWrxB2fWddL8n9Y%2FOczSz25hmtB9ne6vMF9tOrSmLveDC1HaMYAEU%2FaMHiJKzdWtDGGGQRnjZiHSq4WOdOVRb7Fh3Jxhbojl1q%2Fiz7oX0gSiOFTss1YSt%2FUkJlfRx%2B53F4xiGePL4sNouHbxM4sI2TfCNWow7QA%3D&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20240129T202212Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTY277C7OWM%2F20240129%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=29a9aa6c259e281882b540524d684a8d7af22f9c9ef3d9d47177acd5024b8172&hash=90a85f96c8a120172022cefce99939bf39b251368574697bbdc1906cc3fdf540&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=S0196885898905875&tid=spdf-9078af85-0858-40eb-ad00-1f4ffc3b2f27&sid=c53b9a852c67b3495e79ec647b154d32577bgxrqa&type=client&tsoh=d3d3LnNjaWVuY2VkaXJlY3QuY29t&ua=0f135a56025356075954&rr=84d42f95da582f46&cc=us) (Theorem 3.1) that if $A$ and $B$ are subsets of  $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ with $|A|=|B|$ and $0\notin B$, then there is always a matching from $A$ to $B$. However, this matching need not be acyclic.

Update 5: For small enough subsets, we can always guarantee the existence of an acyclic matching. In particular, we have the following theorem from this [paper](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/272332/1-s2.0-S0021869322X00045/1-s2.0-S0021869322000436/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEEIaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJHMEUCIAmCVQuypsMlbemMZl0X%2FBTlxw%2B1hGvTAvXTx%2FYdWw%2BAAiEAoyzbW863SkEN8vOlBhwDaLaqSynirE%2FmLHiDfUJC2j8quwUI%2Bv%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FARAFGgwwNTkwMDM1NDY4NjUiDIVZ%2BxKRS0st%2FrfSeSqPBa%2F3jb1ILggIybjoG%2BEnqBjdLFQD1OIf5XsOBF7isQY59MPCEI0GdDstKyOwvXuO%2BBUMlLhVIbAU7SrpRsnPwdHR9BQbifg5PTDQXCNXszjuCw0j2TeDNFd6bwShZjmhFLmSiR4r4gpPk%2BnBqi%2FSSruQfLecbojAQVaKWZq7qoQXIy567kWcTlZdRvdjIG1GjR%2B%2Be%2FJ%2BKNPgesxWZjC5RXhu0vAg0dsaFkN8xLOmVW2EZTCx%2F7uKA5Xs0Uqkc7rR7SUefcy5RyeamKYxuE%2BTRFAk%2F2jk%2FX4ApRGCr7vuHH5DGXdMCr4pfgbam6gDGeLrIWikymGnWfO7%2BZ9UIOw9Q3Z9OEraDU1y9MktKmAv%2FYJ7KkRPgCcurG5nJkwFd7iEgmjXH7gMou1v45hAS%2FBU6mid%2FWwxM4SWfoeBpS15sTFigDRvlDDsKOdbcf4Yvmq%2B%2B0f1AAiuKYtpda1C1DggyZCQqGcyIM%2BefmAAQxgQYObcARh9Sk3vYQQ2NabyubPqWnRLW4uxn3Fvd%2BntE2LlEWpvG64zpODakGvpo%2FG1ePdFmXAVLsGq4j8zDnUKvx2XiUU3JeYcJNl2aEOdH%2B17eHZrYfO2Mi8f8o0ECjE%2FWejB9iiez4oxXgNBjAHUP%2BG2Je4SkiT5l5eL2rD13zUI36vLhvddYrMNzaDuNLcDcFtkLySCiIFtd7VSJz17nb0Yyb0n8FbOqeowEnR3ZzXmIuP%2BEANxLyDZ7emI8GUsoaPIgdf38nJfPxsiiYz9IRl%2FnbSXK6TN7viQpHrfCTjK4ZUWMS03r7IHjOov8P53%2Bc5WDgR91MgDwo8TFdGSvW3nU7muXJjR9Vp2s1qCfuoRzahIVAhbodHiW6cu2kC%2B6pwwjZjhrQY6sQHWh6EuTtyd3emnn0C28GHJvCX99aJL2kzzzo%2F8Yzpa5aBJTUJB6vCZ9XpJyKAchc0Ke6Bg%2FWsgPMKN4QZU%2FjwotrcBjH%2BVfzH%2FbNMJvvM84xoiUUBrfMTBJC6%2FFGhdI48gyQAcK%2BIu0XYsb%2FRU7qImI5Mmei0OAi1iQSUcrzdEmwddo0ybZh3rTYUBVhO%2B56XyhyvH1Afxa8jnYPkXeb2%2FqITq0Eh%2BSa6wp7zecCPscMo%3D&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20240130T022008Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTY6RJWY7WU%2F20240130%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=600b8535746608ff5f3d314ab8b8724f11260dd5c7bfb857a9e1def60df120a4&hash=3cde6887759d13e263e234a850e8d6cdaee3c535e6977f0c8b8b90f96cc4f2f7&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=S0021869322000436&tid=spdf-2554b4fb-045e-4e52-94db-cc72a97199c3&sid=c53b9a852c67b3495e79ec647b154d32577bgxrqa&type=client&tsoh=d3d3LnNjaWVuY2VkaXJlY3QuY29t&ua=0f135a56025157030559&rr=84d63be8c8aa0c93&cc=us):

Theorem: Let $p$ be a prime number and suppose $A$ and $B$ are finite subsets of $\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}$ with $0\notin B$ which are of the same size $n.$ If
$n\leq\sqrt{\log_2p}-1$, then there exists an acyclic matching $f:A\rightarrow B$.

Update 6: The subset of primes $p$ for which $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ does not have the acyclic matching property is at least of density $\frac{7}{24}$.

Comment: I changed $\mathbb{Z}_p$ to $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ to avoid confusion with the [$p$-adic integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number#p-adic_integers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a similar approach to [LeechLattice](https://mathoverflow.net/users/125498/leechlattice)'s extended comment, consider $A = G \setminus \{0, 1, 3\}$, $B_1 = G \setminus \{0, 1, 2\}$, $B_5 = G \setminus \{0, 1, 6\}$. Over general (i.e. not necessarily prime-order) $\mathbb{Z} / n\mathbb{Z}$ we can define a generating function $F_n$ in $c_0, c_1, c_3$ in which each monomial is weighted by the number of matchings with the corresponding $m_f$, and in both cases these generating functions have a linear recurrence with characteristic polynomial $x^3 - c_1 c_3 x - c_0 c_3^2$. If we then consider slices of the form $n = 6m+k$ we get a linear recurrence with characteristic polynomial $$x^3 - (2 c_1^3 c_3^3 + 3 c_0^2 c_3^4)x^2 + (c_1^6 c_3^6 - 6 c_0^2 c_1^3 c_3^7 + 3 c_0^4 c_3^8)x - c_0^6 c_3^{12}$$

For $n = 6m+1$ we use $B_1$ with initial terms \begin{eqnarray*}F_7 &=& 2c_0 c_1 c_3^2 \\
F_{13} &=& 4 c_0^3 c_1 c_3^6 + 5c_0 c_1^4 c_3^5 \\
F_{19} &=& 6 c_0^5 c_1 c_3^{10} + 35 c_0^3 c_1^4 c_3^9 + 8c_0 c_1^7 c_3^8\end{eqnarray*}

I claim that $$F_{6m+1} = \sum_{j=1}^m \binom{2m+j-1}{3j-2} c_0^{2m-2j+1} c_1^{3j-2} c_3^{4m-j-1}$$

The three base cases are easily checked, and we get a proof by induction with

\begin{eqnarray*}F_{6m+19} &=& (2 c_1^3 c_3^3 + 3 c_0^2 c_3^4) F_{6m+13} - (c_1^6 c_3^6 - 6 c_0^2 c_1^3 c_3^7 + 3 c_0^4 c_3^8) F_{6m+7} + c_0^6 c_3^{12} F_{6m+1} \\
%
&=& (2 c_1^3 c_3^3 + 3 c_0^2 c_3^4) \sum_{j=1}^{m+2} \binom{2m+j+3}{3j-2} c_0^{2m-2j+5} c_1^{3j-2} c_3^{4m-j+7}
\\&& - (c_1^6 c_3^6 - 6 c_0^2 c_1^3 c_3^7 + 3 c_0^4 c_3^8) \sum_{j=1}^{m+1} \binom{2m+j+1}{3j-2} c_0^{2m-2j+3} c_1^{3j-2} c_3^{4m-j+3}
\\&& + c_0^6 c_3^{12} \sum_{j=1}^m \binom{2m+j-1}{3j-2} c_0^{2m-2j+1} c_1^{3j-2} c_3^{4m-j-1} \\
\end{eqnarray*}

First note that all of the exponents of $c_1$ in the recurrence weights are in $\{0,3,6\}$; then

\begin{eqnarray*}[c_1^{3k-2}]F_{6m+19} &=& 
2 \binom{2m+k+2}{3k-5} c_0^{2m-2k+7} c_3^{4m-k+11} +
\\&& 3 \binom{2m+k+3}{3k-2} c_0^{2m-2k+7} c_3^{4m-k+11} -
\\&& \binom{2m+k-1}{3k-8} c_0^{2m-2k+7} c_3^{4m-k+11} +
\\&& 6 \binom{2m+k}{3k-5} c_0^{2m-2k+7} c_3^{4m-k+11} -
\\&& 3 \binom{2m+k+1}{3k-2} c_0^{2m-2k+7} c_3^{4m-k+11} +
\\&& \binom{2m+k-1}{3k-2} c_0^{2m-2k+7} c_3^{4m-k+11} \\
\end{eqnarray*}

so the exponents of $c_0$ and $c_3$ are as desired and the verification of the binomial identity

$$2 \binom{2m+k+2}{3k-5} + 3 \binom{2m+k+3}{3k-2} - \binom{2m+k-1}{3k-8} + 6 \binom{2m+k}{3k-5} - 3 \binom{2m+k+1}{3k-2} + \binom{2m+k-1}{3k-2} = \binom{2m+k+5}{3k-2}$$

is tedious but straightforward.

Finally, note that an acyclic matching requires a value of $j$ for which $\binom{2m+j-1}{3j-2} = 1$, so either $3j = 2$ or $2j=2m+1$, and neither holds for $j \in \mathbb{N}$. Therefore your question is answered in the affirmative for $p = 6m+1$.

---

For $n = 6m + 5$ we use $B_5$ with initial terms \begin{eqnarray*}F_{11} &=& 3c_0 c_1^5 c_3^2 + 5 c_0^3 c_1^2 c_3^3 \\
F_{17} &=& 6 c_0 c_1^8 c_3^5 + 21 c_0^3 c_1^5 c_3^6 + 14 c_0^5 c_1^2 c_3^7 \\
F_{23} &=& 9 c_0 c_1^{11} c_3^8 + 73 c_0^3 c_1^8 c_3^9 + 112 c_0^5 c_1^5 c_3^{10} + 27 c_0^7 c_1^2 c_3^{11}
\end{eqnarray*}

I claim that $$F_{6m+5} = \sum_{j=0}^m \left[ \binom{2m+j+1}{3j+2} + \binom{2m+j}{3j+1} + \binom{2m+j}{3j-1} \right] c_0^{2m-2j+1}c_1^{3j+2}c_3^{4m-j-1}$$

Proof is similar but even more tedious. See appendix.

None of the three binomial coefficients in $\binom{2m+j+1}{3j+2} + \binom{2m+j}{3j+1} + \binom{2m+j}{3j-1}$ can be $1$ for $j \in \mathbb{N}$, and since they are non-negative their sum can likewise never be $1$. Therefore your question is answered in the affirmative also for $p = 6m+5 > 5$, which completes the classification.

---

##### Appendix

Here's some Sage code to verify the core binomial identity for the $6m+1$ and the $6m+5$ cases:

```
var('m,j')

def coeffF1(m, j):
    return binomial(2*m+j-1, 3*j-2)

def coeffF5(m, j):
    return binomial(2*m+j+1,3*j+2) + binomial(2*m+j,3*j+1) + binomial(2*m+j,3*j-1)

def proof(coeffFn):
    zero = coeffFn(m+3, j) - 2*coeffFn(m+2, j-1) - 3*coeffFn(m+2, j) + coeffFn(m+1, j-2) - 6*coeffFn(m+1, j-1) + 3*coeffFn(m+1, j) - coeffFn(m,j)
    print(zero)
    print(bool(zero == 0))

proof(coeffF1)
proof(coeffF5)
```

Comment: I think these examples can be extended to cover the other equivalence classes mod 6 and show that no cyclic group of order greater than 5 has the acyclic matching property.

Comment: Your solution is elegant, by the way. Thank you! Let us discuss this problem further, Peter Taylor and @LeechLattice, if you are interested. (Please send me an email at 'mohsenmath88@gmail.com' for further discussion).

Comment: For non-prime n, things are much easier. If $n$ is not a prime, take an element $a\in \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ with an order less than $n$.  Choose $x\in (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})\setminus <a>$ and set $A=<a>$ and $B=(<a>\cup \{x\})\setminus \{0\}$. Then there is no matching from $A$ to $B$, let alone an acyclic matching.

Answer (score 5):

This is not an answer, but it's too long to be included in the comment section.

**Conjecture:** For any prime $p \geq 7$, $p \neq 29$, let

$   \begin{equation}
A=B=
    \begin{cases}
        \{1,2,...,p-5,p-3\} & \text{if } p = 1 \text{ mod } 6\\
        \{1,2,...,p-7,p-5\} & \text{if } p = 5 \text{ mod } 6\\
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}$

then there are no acyclic matchings from $A$ to $B$.

**Known:**

1. The conjecture is true up to $p=47$.
2. For the case $p=29$, let $A=B=\{1,2,...,20,22\}$. Then there are no acyclic matchings from $A$ to $B$.

**Remarks:**

Let $G$ be a graph on the vertex set $\{(0,a) : a \in A\} \cup \{(1,b) : b \in B\}$, where two vertices $(0,u)$ and $(1,v)$ are connected iff $u+v \notin A$, and the color of the edge is given by $u+v$. Then every matching $f$ amounts to a perfect matching $M$ on the graph $G$, where every vertex $(0,u)$ is connected with $(1,f(u))$, and the multiplicity function is given by the edges in $M$ colored by a certain color.

The graph $G$ has a periodic structure, so the perfect matchings $M$ can be enumerated by linear recurrences (cf. [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/388703/growth-of-the-permanent-of-some-band-matrix/)). In this way it may be possible to prove that, for every perfect matching $M$, there exists a different perfect matching $M'$ such that for every color $c$, the number of $c$-colored edges is the same in $M$ and $M'$.

Below are the graphs $G$ corresponding to $p=37$ and $p=41$ respectively.
[image]
[image]

Update: My conjecture is false for all primes of the form $30n+29$. For such a prime there is exactly one matching with $m_f$ nonzero only at $p-6$ and $p-1$.

Comment: Ah, ok. But it is still correct that $f$ is involutive?

Comment: @FedorPetrov There is no longer the claim about $f$ being involutive. The multiplicities of $m_f$ should be computed among all $f$, either involutive or not.

Comment: But if $f$ is not involutive, does not $f^{-1}\ne f$ have the same multiplicity function as $f$?

Comment: @FedorPetrov The point is to rule out involutive $f$s having the same $m_f$ with non-involutive $f$s. Sometimes an involutive matching $f$ has unique $m_f$ among involutive matchings, but its $m_f$ is not unique among all matchings.

Comment: Well, in the definition all matchings are considered, not only involutive. But if $f$ is acyclic, then it must be involutive, right?

Comment: @FedorPetrov Yes.

Comment: @LeechLattice Your approach is interesting. In your conjecture, if we assume that there is an acyclic matching $f$ from $A$ to $B$, then $f$ is involutive and also it must have a fixed point.